# How do I bake a Procedural Emission Material into a Texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, texture-baking, procedural, emission

I followed [this tutorial on how to make a galaxy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCBW4fNAjBg) and now I want to import it into UE4. Problem is, UE4 uses a HLSL, and Blender doesn't. I read somewhere that you can bake it into a texture, but trying to do this has left me with nothing. So now I'm stuck with this really cool galaxy and nothing to do with it.

[image]
[image]

Here's what I have, I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: bumping cause I need help

Comment: It appears that you have a volumetric.  There's not really any such thing as baking a volumetric to anything, except via just rendering it.  In which case, place a camera and hit f12.

Comment: @Nathan What about exporting the noise textures that were used to create the volumetric, is that possible?

Comment: I can't really see your nodes, the resolution of the image is too low, but they're probably 3D, aren't they?  You can't really export 3D data to a 2D image.  The best you could do is take slices of it and export to multiple 2D images.

Comment: @Nathan I linked the tutorial I used to create this, the nodes are the same. As far as I'm concerned Noise textures can't be 3D?

Comment: I'm not watching a 20 min video to know exactly what you did, sorry.  If the noise texture node says 3D on it, it's 3D (and yes, they sure can be 3D, that's part of the point of them.)

Comment: @Nathan The Gradient Texture is Spherical but my Noise Node is set to 2D. I would only need to noise texture if I want to import it into UE4, as I can replicate the 3D look inside of UE4. There should be a way to extract what the noise texture made.

Comment: If the noise texture is 2D, then yes, you can bake it to an image.  Again, I can't see what kind of texture coords you're using, but you'd want to remap that to the 0,1 range to fit in the space of an image (and then undo that remapping wherever you used it.)

Comment: @Nathan I added an image showing the noise texture up close

Comment: You're using object coordinates, so the bounds of the noise texture are equal to your greatest and lowest vertex positions in X and Y.  If your volumetric fits inside a standard cube, you'd remap object coordinates from -1,1 to 0,1 and bake to an image.  If it fits inside a cube scaled up double, you'd remap object coordinates from -2,2 to 0,1.

Comment: @Nathan So I change the location xy or the vertex xy in the mapping nodes? And from there do I bake to diffuse?

Comment: We're getting far from your original question, and there aren't enough details in your question to give you solid answers.  I would recommend a new question, "How can I bake the noise texture used here to an image?" and then linking the file so people can see the details of your mesh (and of everything else.)